# Why do we need a generic here? Isn't the protocol enough?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I found the following example on the web about using generics together with protocols, however I don't understand why do we need generics at all, when all we need is to use a protocol.

We define a protocol:

```
protocol Healthy {
    mutating func setAlive(status: Bool)
    var health: Int { get }
}
```

And then a function using a generic adotping that protocol

```
func check<T:Healthy>(inout object: T) {
    if (object.health <= 0) {
        object.setAlive(false)
    }
}
```

I've changed the code as below and everything is still fine.

```
func check( object: inout Healthy) {
    if (object.health <= 0) {
        object.setAlive(status: false)
    }
}
```

Or not?

The only reason I could think of to use a generic there, if it's a protocol has an associatedtype and it can't used as an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They express different things. With

```
func check(object: inout Healthy) {
```

The `object` argument can be *any* `Healthy` conforming instance. Therefore, you could do this:

```
protocol Healthy {}

struct Foo : Healthy {}
struct Bar : Healthy {}

func check(object: inout Healthy) {
    object = Bar()
}

var h: Healthy = Foo()
check(object: &h)
print(h) // Bar()
```

We called `check(object:)` and passed `h` (which holds a `Foo` instance) as the `inout` argument, but ended up with `h` holding a `Bar` instance.

You'll note that this means we cannot simply call `check(object:)` with a concrete-typed `inout` argument. The following doesn't compile:

```
var h = Foo()

// compiler error: Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 
// implicit conversion from 'Foo' to 'Healthy' requires a temporary
check(object: &h)
```

Because `check(object:)` could assign an *arbitrary* `Healthy` conforming instance to the `object` argument, which is not assignable to a `Foo` variable.

However, with

```
func check<T : Healthy>(object: inout T) {
```

The `object` argument is a single *specific* concrete type that conforms to `Healthy` (and this type is satisfied at the call-site). You cannot just assign an arbitrary `Healthy` conforming instance to it, as it might not be compatible with the variable type being passed as the `inout` argument.

This therefore now allows you to call it with a concrete-typed `inout` argument. We can now say:

```
protocol Healthy {
    var alive: Bool { get set }
}

struct Foo : Healthy {
    var alive: Bool
}
struct Bar : Healthy {
    var alive: Bool
}

func check<T : Healthy>(object: inout T) {

    object.alive = false

    // illegal
    // object = Bar()
}

var h = Foo(alive: true)
check(object: &h)
```

(note `h` is able to be typed as `Foo`)

So in most cases, you'll likely want to make the method generic rather than having a protocol-typed `inout` parameter, as you'll likely want to be dealing with concrete types.

Comment: From your answer, I deduce that the main reason to use a generic in this example is to avoid assignments inside the function (which would be conceptually wrong in this case given the inout parameter). Correct?

Comment: @Patrick Well the main reason to use a generic is to enforce that the `inout` argument is a single concrete type (you *cannot* pass a concrete-typed variable to an `inout Healthy` parameter). It doesn't avoid assignments in the function, you could still make an assignment to the argument – but the compiler enforces that the type you're assigning is of type `T`, not an *arbitrary* `Healthy` conforming type.

Comment: @Patrick For example, `func check<T : Healthy>(object: inout T, other: T) { object = other }` is legal. The ability to assign to an `inout` argument isn't conceptually wrong – it's a feature that using `inout` allows for.

Comment: Mhm oh yeah, I added these 2 lines inside the func and it compiles correctly.  let bar:Healthy = Bar(); object = bar

Comment: So its just about enforcing to use concrete types. Although from a pratical point of view, I dont see what could change, in this example.

Comment: @Patrick Not sure what you mean – the change that it makes is what you can call the function with. With `inout Healthy` you can only pass a `Healthy` variable as the `inout` argument – passing a concrete-typed variable is illegal. With `inout T` (where `T : Healthy`) you can pass any concrete-typed variable to the `inout` argument, where that concrete type conforms to `Healthy`. You cannot pass a `Healthy` variable to `inout T`.

Comment: What I mean is; why should I choose one over the other in this case? What is the advantage to use a concrete type in the example above? Which is actually my original question. I Understand the difference between concrete type and protocol, but the question is "why is a concrete type used here?"

Comment: @Patrick You should choose the one that suit your needs. If you're talking in terms of *any* `Healthy` conforming type, you want `inout Healthy`. If you're talking in terms of any one specific concrete type that conforms to `Healthy`, you want a generic placeholder. Obviously don't use `inout Healthy` if you're talking in terms of concrete types – throwing away type information by needlessly upcasting to `Healthy` isn't good practice. You should always talk in terms of the strongest types for your values.

Comment: Ok. So it depends on the context. The function itself, isn't enough to explain why I should use a generic over a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is using an `inout` (ugh) and not returning a value means that the generic is not required.

When I would use a generic for this example is if the method signature was like this...

```
func check<T:Healthy>(object: T) -> T {
}
```

This would then ensure that the type of object passed in and the type returned are the same type.

Without the generic you could pass in an instance of...

```
struct A: Healthy {}
```

and return an instance of...

```
struct B: Healthy {}
```

Hmm... maybe this is still the case with the `inout`. Can you create another struct that conforms to the protocol and change the `object` to an instance of your new struct? Maybe... will have to check that later.

Comment: I tried, and you can assign a variable in both cases as long as you declare it correctly (concrete type in the case of generics, protocol in the other case). So, I dont see the reason to use a generic, unless you have a constrain (such as returning the same generic object - as you specified).