# Where is 'Any' declared/implemented in Swift 3 and onwards?

Tags: swift

#### `Any` as standard protocol (Swift 2.2) to ...?

Prior to Swift 3.0, `Any` was described as *"The protocol to which all types implicitly conform."*, and was implemented, in the Standard Library, as [a `typealias` for `protocol<>`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/global/alias/):

> ```
> typealias Any = protocol<>
> ```
>
> The protocol to which all types implicitly conform.

From Swift 3.0 an onwards, its usage and meaning is seemingly unchanged, but I can no longer find—in the fluidly changing Language Reference of Swift—any explicit reference to it.

- Where is `Any` declared/implemented in Swift 3.0 an onwards, and where is this documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `Any` has been removed from the Standard Library and is now a keyword/builtin type

At the time of the implementation the Swift evolution proposal

- [SE-0095: Replace protocol syntax with P1 & P2 syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0095-any-as-existential.md)

for Swift 3, `Any` was removed from the Swift Standard Library and made into a keyword/builtin type. Its meaning and behaviour remains the same.

Citing the evolution proposal above:

> The existing `Any` typealias, which represents all types that conform
>   to zero or more protocols (i.e. all types), **will become a keyword**.
>   Its meaning will not change.

Citing the updates in the `CHANGELOG.md` for the [the commit associated with removing the `Any` typealias from the Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7b9e5de7b7b0f22c0c015b9ffd43b234e8f101ee/CHANGELOG.md):

> The empty protocol composition, the `Any` type, was previously defined
>   as being `protocol<>`. **This has been removed from the standard
>   library and `Any` is now a keyword with the same behaviour**.

In [another prior commit related to implementing SE-0095](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/a6dad0091bbb099b1c44d691204b5861e3332a1d#diff-b315af779c9d25e8d63b7866efdbff17R571), we can spot the changes migrating `Any` from the Standard Library and changing it into a builtin keyword.

> [SE-0095] Initial parsing implementation for '`&`' composition syntax
>   This commit defines the ‘`Any`’ keyword, implements parsing for
>   composing types with an infix ‘`&`’, and provides a fixit to convert
>   ‘`protocol<>`’
>
> ...
>
> **`include/swift/AST/ASTContext.h:`**
>
> ```
>   // Builtin type and simple types that are used frequently.
>   ...
> + const CanType TheAnyType; /// This is 'Any', the empty protocol composition
> ```
>
> **`include/swift/AST/KnownIdentifiers.def:`**
>
> ```
>   ...
>   IDENTIFIER(Self)
> + IDENTIFIER(Any)
> ```

#### Where is this keyword now documented?

Except for the various changelogs describing this migration, the documentation of `Any` as a keyword can now be found in [the Language Reference - Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html):

> **Keywords and Punctuation**
>
> ...
>
> - Keywords used in expressions and types: `as`, **`Any`**, `catch`, ...

As well as, subtly, in main grammar description of [the Language Reference - Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html):

> **Grammar of a type**
>
> ...
>
> *type -> metatype-type*
>
> *type ->* `Any`
>
> *type ->* `Self`
>
> ...

Finally, as before, (although now being a keyword/non-stdlib-type) `Any` is still simply described a special type that can be use to represent any type at all. Citing [the Language Guide - Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

> **Type Casting for `Any` and `AnyObject`**
>
> Swift provides two special types for working with nonspecific types:
>
> - `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function
>     types.
>
> ...