# operator implementations in swift

Tags: swift, operators, swift-protocols

In the following shift playground with operator `+=` I get a compile error:

```
protocol Value {
    func get() -> Float
    mutating func set(to:Float)
}

func += (a:inout Value, b:Value) {
    let t = a.get() + b.get()
    a.set(to:t)
}

struct S : Value {
    var t:Float
    func get() -> Float {
        return t
    }
    mutating func set(to:Float) {
        t = to
    }
}

var s1 = S(t:3)
let s2 = S(t:4)
s1 += s2 // Compiler error: Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two 'S' operands
```

Now if I redefine my operator as

```
func += (a:inout S, b:Value) {
    let t = a.get() + b.get()
    a.set(to:t)
}
```

it works just fine. Why can I not define `+=` with the left hand side as a `Value`?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44387949/2976878. You can't pass an `S` variable to an `inout Value` parameter as the callee is free to assign an instance of some other `Value` conforming type to it. You probably want to make it generic instead.

Comment: Not related to your issue but why don't you simply declare a property value in your protocol `protocol Value {
    var value: Float { get set }
}` `struct S: Value {
    var value: Float
}` 
`func += <T: Value>(a: inout T, b: Value) {
    a += b
}` ?

Comment: Because I am also going to extend `Float` to conform to `Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hamish stated in the comments, you can't use the protocol `Value` for the `inout` variable because the called function is free to assign an instance of some other `Value` conforming type to it.

Instead, you should make it generic like this:

```
func +=<T: Value>(a:inout T, b:Value) {
    let t = a.get() + b.get()
    a.set(to:t)
}
```