# Error "Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than ..." when passing in a protocol type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, inout

I am coming from C++ to Swift. I have this situation with respect to protocols and structs (I am working with random numbers):
(1) A protocol `RandomPr` that specifies there are methods such as `randFloat()` that returns a Float between 0 and 1.
(2) A struct `RandomS` that implements `RandomPr` using a "real" random number generator.
(3) A struct `FakeRandomS` that implements `RandomPr`, but has additional methods such as `loadFloat()` to load an array of Floats that are then regurgitated when I call `randFloat()` on a `FakeRandomS` instance. (For testing purposes.)

Now I have a function `DoSomething(rng: inout RandomPr)`, which I want to use with both `RandomS` and `FakeRandomS`. The parameter has to be in-out as I need to update the RNG (whether it is real or fake). No problem calling `DoSomething` with an instance of `RandomS`.

But if I do

```
var fakeRng = FakeRandomS()
fakeRng.loadFloat([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
DoSomething(rng: &fakeRng)
```

I get an error "Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than 'FakeRandomS'. The suggested fix is to define `fakeRng` as

```
var fakeRng: RandomPr = FakeRandomS()
```

But now trying to call `loadFloat` on `fakeRng` fails because `RandomPr` doesn't have a method `loadFloat`, and the compiler doesn't see that `fakeRng` does have one.

I tried making another protocol `FakeRandomPr` that contains the extra methods that `FakeRandomS` has, and defining

```
var fakeRng: RandomPr & FakeRandomPr = FakeRandomS()
```

but, frustratingly, I now get the "Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than ..." error back again.

I could do the equivalent of this in C++ without problems (a pure abstract base class and two child classes, passed in by reference), and it didn't matter that one of the things I wanted to pass in has extra methods. I want to translate this into protocols and structs. What is the Swift solution?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Swift solution?

You may need to use generics:

```
func doSomething<RP: RandomPr>(rng: inout RP) {
    //...
}
```

---

Swift is not just *another syntax of C++*, better think in Swifty way.

Comment: Thank you for this - yes, it works! I am trying to think Swiftly, and it seemed Swift-like enough to make a protocol, specify that `DoSomething()` accepted anything conforming to this protocol, and supply two structs. In fact, my non-generic solution works if there are no extra methods or if the parameter to `DoSomething()` is not inout. It is only the combination of extra methods and trying to pass something as an inout parameter that causes trouble. I know that passing an inout parameter is not the same as calling by reference, but clearly there is something I don't understand.

Comment: @GordonMonro> _passing an inout parameter is not the same as calling by reference_. True. In fact calling by reference would be more like using reference type (class) without `inout` in Swift. You could have translated your C++ code into Swift more easily if you used class. When you can clarify what you do not understand you can start a new thread for that.

Answer (score 1):

OK - I posted this a while ago. Now I have come back to it, and obtained some understanding, thanks to the answer by Hamish in [Why do we need a generic here? Isn't the protocol enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387949/why-do-we-need-a-generic-here-isnt-the-protocol-enough?rq=3).

I did not realise that with an inout parameter with type given as a protocol, the whole input object could be replaced by something with a completely different type (in Hamish's example an object of type struct Foo is replaced by an object of type struct Bar). If I then make subsequent use of the object, I can't assume anything about it except that it satisfies the protocol. The compiler tries to enforce this, which is why it objected to additional methods on one of the structs.

Belated thanks to Hamish.